# Finding the volume of a cone with a cylinder cut out?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

This shape above the plane $z=0$ lies within the cone $z=4-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and outside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$.

I attempted doing this in cylindrical, but was stumped on evaluating the bounds of $r$ when evaluated in the order $dzdrd\theta$. I know the lower bound of $r$ must be $1$, but I have to write the outer bound, the cone, as a function of $\theta$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "roof" will be the cone. The integration area $D$ has to be within the cone (so $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq4$) and outside the cylinder (so $x^2+y^2\geq1$). Thus
\begin{align}
\iint_D(4-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\,dA & = \int_1^4\int_0^{2\pi}(4-r)r\,d\theta\,dr
=2\pi\int_1^4(4r-r^2)\,dr \\ \ \\
&=2\pi\left.\left( 2r^2-\frac{r^3}3\right)\right|_1^4
=2\pi\left(32-\frac{64}3-2+\frac13\right)=18\pi.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. However, I'm checking it using basic geometric formulas and I get the volume of the cone is $4.19$ by $\pi r^2 \frac{h}{3}$... why is it so small?

Comment: $\pi\times4^2\times4/3>67$.

Comment: Oops, I was using $1$ as the radius.

Comment: I just noticed that I had a silly integration mistake. It is corrected now.